# Angular 6 Exception Handling

Tags: angular

We have a dynamic dashboard with lots of (widgets)components that come from other teams.  Our problem is that if one component crashes it takes down the whole dashboard. Each component inherits from a common component and also is wrapped in a common parent component. Is there a way to catch the exception in Angular so the whole component does not crash the system outside of wrapping each function in a try catch?

Comment: Angular comes with central error handling capabilities: https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler, good explanation also at https://medium.com/@aleixsuau/error-handling-angular-859d529fa53a. If these don't work, please specify what kind of errors happen on your dashboard app. if the app fails to compile, the errors needs to be caught outside of angular I assume

Comment: It does compile. Sometimes its simple stuff like the field is undefined when it should be an empty array.  I knew about the ErrorHandler but was looking for something more localized to the component itself.